# Converting dictionary with known indices to a multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary with entries labelled as `{(k,i): value, ...}`. I now want to convert this dictionary into a 2d array where the value given for an element of the array at position `[k,i]` is the value from the dictionary with label `(k,i)`. The length of the rows will not necessarily be of the same size (e.g. row `k = 4` may go up to index `i = 60` while row `k = 24` may go up to index `i = 31`). Due to the asymmetry, it is fine to make all additional entries in a particular row equal to 0 in order to have a rectangular matrix.

Comment: Sample input/output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach -

```
# Get keys (as indices for output) and values as arrays
idx = np.array(d.keys())
vals = np.array(d.values())

# Get dimensions of output array based on max extents of indices
dims = idx.max(0)+1

# Setup output array and assign values into it indexed by those indices
out = np.zeros(dims,dtype=vals.dtype)
out[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]] = vals
```

We could also use sparse matrices to get the final output. e.g. with [`coordinate format sparse matrices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html). This would be memory efficient when kept as sparse matrices. So, the last step could be replaced by something like this -

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

out = coo_matrix((vals, (idx[:,0], idx[:,1])), dims).toarray()
```

Sample run -

```
In [70]: d
Out[70]: {(1, 4): 120, (2, 2): 72, (2, 3): 100, (5, 2): 88}

In [71]: out
Out[71]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 120],
       [  0,   0,  72, 100,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,  88,   0,   0]])
```

---

To make it generic for ndarrays of any number of dimensions, we can use linear-indexing and use `np.put` to assign values into the output array. Thus, in our first approach, just replace the last step of assigning values with something like this -

```
np.put(out,np.ravel_multi_index(idx.T,dims),vals)
```

Sample run -

```
In [106]: d
Out[106]: {(1,0,0): 99, (1,0,4): 120, (2,0,2): 72, (2,1,3): 100, (3,0,2): 88}

In [107]: out
Out[107]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0]],

       [[ 99,   0,   0,   0, 120],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,  72,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0, 100,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,  88,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dictionary-of-keys sparse format that can be built from a dictionary like this.

Starting with `Divakar's` `d` sample:

```
In [1189]: d={(1, 4): 120, (2, 2): 72, (2, 3): 100, (5, 2): 88}
```

Make an empty sparse matrix of the right shape and dtype:

```
In [1190]: M=sparse.dok_matrix((6,5),dtype=int)
In [1191]: M
Out[1191]: 
<6x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
```

Add the `d` values via a dictionary `update`.  This works because this particular sparse format is a `dict` subclass.  Be ware though that this trick is not documented (at least not that I'm aware of):

```
In [1192]: M.update(d)
In [1193]: M
Out[1193]: 
<6x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [1194]: M.A    # convert M to numpy array (handy display trick)
Out[1194]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 120],
       [  0,   0,  72, 100,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,  88,   0,   0]])
```

`M` can be converted to the other sparse formats, `coo`, `csr`.  In fact `sparse` does this kind of conversion by itself, depending on the use (display, calculation, etc).

```
In [1196]: print(M)
  (2, 3)    100
  (5, 2)    88
  (1, 4)    120
  (2, 2)    72
```