# how to convert a dictionary to a matrix in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

i have dictionary that looks like this, (i,j): number..
(i and j are letters):

{(N,M): 10, (N,K): 1  (H,K): 13...}

how to creat a 2d matrix that looks like this:

```
   N   K   M   H

N  1   -   -   -

K  1   10  -   -

M  10  12  15  -

H  4   13  6   2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear which type of 2D array you need, but if you want to keep the letters as indices, maybe pandas is the best option.

```
data = {('N', 'M'): 10, ('N', 'K'): 1, ('H', 'K'): 13}
keys = ['N', 'K', 'M', 'H']

import pandas as pd
matrix = pd.DataFrame(columns=keys, index=keys)
for p in pos:
    matrix.loc[p[0], p[1]] = pos[p]
```

It is also possible to do it with numpy, if you can do without the letters.

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((len(keys), len(keys)))
for d in data:
    i = keys.index(d[0])
    j = keys.index(d[1])
    matrix[i, j] = data[d]
```

If you must use only python's built-in objects, you can create a matrix with lists.

```
matrix = [[None] * len(keys) for i in range(len(keys))]
for d in data:
    i = keys.index(d[0])
    j = keys.index(d[1])
    matrix[i][j] = data[d]
```

Finally, you can also have a look at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729912/converting-dictionary-with-known-indices-to-a-multidimensional-array), but I am afraid the solutions there will not work with letters as indices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using only built-in Python facilities:

```
letters = 'NKMH'
data = {('N', 'N'): 1,
        ('K', 'N'): 1, ('K', 'K'): 1,
        ('M', 'N'): 10, ('M', 'K'): 12, ('M', 'M'): 15,
        ('H', 'N'): 4, ('H', 'K'): 13, ('H', 'M'): 6, ('H', 'H'): 2}

# Dictionaries to make translating between letters <-> indices easy.
letter_to_index = dict(zip(letters, range(len(letters))))
index_to_letter = dict(zip(range(len(letters)), letters))

# Preallocate matrix.
matrix = [['-' for _ in range(len(letters))]
            for _ in range(len(letters))]

# Place data into the matrix.
for (row, col), value in data.items():
    i, j = letter_to_index[row], letter_to_index[col]
    matrix[i][j] = value

# Pretty print result.
print('  ', '   '.join(letters))
for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    print('{}  {}'.format(
        index_to_letter[i], '  '.join('{:<2}'.format(value) for value in row)))
```

Output:

```
   N   K   M   H
N  1   -   -   - 
K  1   1   -   - 
M  10  12  15  - 
H  4   13  6   2
```